# R - devtools Github install fails

Tags: r, curl, github

Trying to use Hadleys devtools package I am getting a certification error:

```
install_github("devtools")
Installing github repo(s) devtools/master from hadley
Installing devtools.zip from https://github.com/hadley/devtools/archive/master.zip
  Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Google search tells me that this is a curl issue. I am no nearer. 
Using "git" from the command line I can pick up anything I want from github, - I don't get this error. It only appears when I try to connect to github from R.

I am using ubuntu 12.10, libcurl 7.22.0 and R 3.0

Does anyone have an idea what to do to fix this?

Sincerely
H.

Comment: Can you provide the full output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Googling some more I found that curl related issues in R had been solved by reinstalling RCurl. I tried that, and then

Comment: And then ? What a suspense !

Comment: Googling some more I found that curl related issues in R had been solved by reinstalling RCurl. I tried that, and then....(sorry, lost connection) this worked. SessionInfo tells me that Rcurl is loaded into namespace so I suspect that there was some issue between my then current Rcurl and my curl library.

Comment: you can clone the directory then R CMD build and R CMD install on your local machine. I recently ran into this same issue trying to install ffbase from github and that was how I ended up working around it

Comment: also theres something funny about trying to install a package using a function from that same package

Answer (score 5):

This issue is resolved. There was some mismatch between the version of RCurl and the curl library. Re-installing RCurl fixed the problem.

Comment: I install RCurl and got same errors. How to fix this?

Comment: I was able to do the opposite to fix this - installed Curl (Windows using Chocolatey - CMD> choco install curl). Then restarted R, and was good.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ git clone git://github.com/hadley/devtools.git
$ R CMD build devtools
$ R CMD install devtools_1.2.99.tar.gz
```

or just

```
$ git clone git://github.com/hadley/devtools.git
$ R CMD install devtools
```

both worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04. Someone else can weigh in on whether there's any difference in building first then installing from tarball or not. I would guess no, but I have no idea

edit:
trying this on os X

```
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘devtools’ ...
** libs
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/devtools’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/devtools’
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, 
That is how I did it with rCharts recently. But I would like to be able to access this directly. Which seems to be working for now (after I updated RCurl)