# error setting certificate verify locations, install_github

Tags: r, github, installation, devtools, rcurl

I am trying to install a package from github, but I keep getting an error when I
use `install_github`.

```
library(devtools)
install_github(repo="swirl", username="ncarchedi")
Installing github repo(s) swirl/master from ncarchedi
Downloading swirl.zip from https://github.com/ncarchedi/swirl/archive/master.zip
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RCurl/CurlSSL/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
```

I have tried to install several different packages
(including an updated version of ggmap), and I always get the same error. It
must have something to do with RCurl, but I don't understand what the problem
is, or how to fix it. I have devtools (Version 1.3) and RCurl
(Version 1.95-4.1). I am running R version 3.0.1 ("Good Sport") on mac.

Results from `sessionInfo()`

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.1 bitops_1.0-5   devtools_1.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.3 httr_0.2       memoise_0.1    parallel_3.0.1  stringr_0.6.2 
[7] tools_3.0.1    whisker_0.3-2
```

Comment: Looks like an RCurl problem. Does this file actually exist: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RCurl/CurlSSL/cacert.pem?

Comment: hmm, works for me on mac, 10.8.5. This comment on installing rcharts may be of use https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/135#issuecomment-20140615

Comment: Yeah, what @Thomas said, do you have libcurl installed? Try locate curl-config on the command line to see if it is installed, if not directions on installing here http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html  Though maybe you couldn't have installed RCurl without curl already installed...

Comment: Yes, I have RCurl installed, in exactly the place that you reference (/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RCurl/CurlSSL/cacert.pem). There are 3 things in the directory: boost.pem, ca-bundle.crt, and cacert.pem.

Comment: This one suggests trying to reinstall RCurl http://stackoverflow.com/a/16547624/1091766 - Try re-installing RCurl

Comment: I think I have libcurl installed. When I try locate curl-config, I get

Comment: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/bin/curl-config
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/bin/curl-config
/usr/bin/curl-config
/usr/share/man/man1/curl-config.1.gz`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas and @ScottChamberlain! Deleting and reinstalling RCurl fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SO answer ([R - devtools Github install fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467725/r-devtools-github-install-fails/16547624#16547624)) to a similar question suggests trying to reinstall RCurl - which (I'm guessing here) may fix the path to curl on your machine, in any case, try that.

Comment: I can not fix with this solution.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is due to a change in the R package `curl`.

You can work around the issue as follows:

1). Open a new MRO session and remove the packages `curl` and `httr`:

```
remove.packages(c("curl","httr"))
```

2). Restart MRO and install the packages again, this time using `install.packages()` function:

```
install.packages(c("curl", "httr"))
```

3).  Set the environment variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE`:

```
Sys.setenv(CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/utils/microsoft-r-open-3.4.3/lib64/R/lib/microsoft-r-cacert.pem")
```

4). Try installing a package using `install_github()` from github(this should now work):

For example:

```
install_github("ropensci/tokenizer")
```

#### Reference:

[rvest read_html function does not work](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/aec2c852-109a-4fc3-95f9-6fe61e779adf/rvest-readhtml-function-does-not-work?forum=ropen)

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 server, I had to install libcurl4-openssl-dev before I could install curl. Then Sys.setenv(CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib/microsoft-r-cacert.pem")

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while pushing changes to github 
**git config --global http.sslverify "false"** will solve the problem

here is original discussion going on
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1484

Comment: it will work, but not a good practice to skip ssl verification.