# Curl certificate location error in R

Tags: r, git, curl

I get the following error when trying to use `devtools:install_github` with R 3.4.1 on Windows 7:

```
> devtools::install_github("baptiste/ggflags")
Installation failed: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

However, the exact same command works fine on the same system using R 3.3.2. The .Rprofiles are identical for both installations. I've tried re-installing `RCurl` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693518/error-setting-certificate-verify-locations-install-github) post, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was connected to proxy server settings.

This worked:  https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/116

Edit your environ file - file.edit('~/.Renviron') - to change your https proxy accordingly