# how can i get the package from 'github' using 'devtools'

Tags: r, devtools

I'm using the neurobase package in R. In this package i need to download other package from github then, i'll use the devtools and get the error.

```
> devtools::install_github("muschellij2/ms.lesion")
Installation failed: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: microsoft-r-cacert.pem 
  CApath: none
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, microsoft R-3.4.3, RCurl-1.95.4.9

Already did reinstall the libcurl4-openssl-dev, libssl-dev
using this code

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: see https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/116 and https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1610. in short, you need to set environment variables `Sys.getenv(http_proxy=“mycompanyproxy:8080”); Sys.getenv(https_proxy=“mycompanyproxy:8080”)`

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693518/error-setting-certificate-verify-locations-install-github and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467725/r-devtools-github-install-fails/16547624#16547624

Comment: Hmm.. i think about it'll need to proxy setting  could you give me a help?

`> ie_proxy_info()`

`NULL`

Comment: You can’t use that function on Linux. It is only for Windows. You will need your IT to give you the proxy or get it from your browser